# trying to eliminate duplicates in an array but not working

Tags: java

This is a hw assignment technically but I am doing it for practice not for a grade. Here is the problem with my solution so far:

```
/**
     * smoosh() takes an array of ints. On completion the array contains the
     * same numbers, but wherever the array had two or more consecutive
     * duplicate numbers, they are replaced by one copy of the number. Hence,
     * after smoosh() is done, no two consecutive numbers in the array are the
     * same.
     * 
     * Any unused elements at the end of the array are set to -1.
     * 
     * For example, if the input array is [ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 3 3 3 1 1 0 ], it
     * reads [ 0 1 0 3 1 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ] after smoosh()
     * completes.
     * 
     * @param ints
     *            the input array.
     **/

    public static void smoosh(int[] ints) {
    // Fill in your solution here. (Ours is fourteen lines long, not
    // counting
    // blank lines or lines already present in this file.)

    int index = ints.length - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < ints.length; i++) {
        if (ints[i] == ints[i - 1]) {
            for (int j = i; j < ints.length - 1; j++) {
                ints[j] = ints[j + 1];
            }
            ints[index] = -1;
            index--;
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: updated code here is my results:

Let's smoosh arrays!

```
smooshing [  3  7  7  7  4  5  5  2  0  8  8  8  8  5  ]:
[  3  7  7  4  5  2  0  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]
*** ERROR:  BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)
    at hw3.TestHelper.verify(TestHelper.java:26)
    at hw3.Homework3.main(Homework3.java:72)
smooshing [  6  6  6  6  6  3  6  3  6  3  3  3  3  3  3  ]:
[  6  6  6  3  6  3  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  ]
*** ERROR:  BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)
    at hw3.TestHelper.verify(TestHelper.java:26)
    at hw3.Homework3.main(Homework3.java:82)
smooshing [  4  4  4  4  4  ]:
[  4  4  -1  -1  -1  ]
*** ERROR:  BAD SMOOSH!!!  No cookie.
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)
    at hw3.TestHelper.verify(TestHelper.java:26)
    at hw3.Homework3.main(Homework3.java:91)
smooshing [  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ]:
[  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ]
```

I am getting a bit closer but it is still working incorrectly so something must be wrong with my logic

Comment: if a == b then a = b; // useless, don't you think so?

Comment: You set the same value back, so in essence your loop doesn't do anything...

Comment: I got the increment to work but for some reason it is skipping some duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look on how to work with Collections. Take a look to the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

I would tackle your problem as follows:

1. Create a `Set` object
2. Insert the values from your array in the set (a set cannot have duplicates, so it will not allow you to insert one), and
3. Return the resulting set (or convert it to an array) and do whatever you need to do with it.

So, it would be something like this:

```
public Integer deduplicateArray(int[] values) {
    Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>(values.length);
    for(Integer i : values) {
        if(!intSet.add(i))
            System.out.println("Value " + i + " is duplicated and was not added");
    }
    return intSet.toArray();
}
```

Notice that you specify that the set will contain `Integer` objects (not `int` values), because a Collection can only hold objects. You can use an `Integer` object as any other `int` value:

```
// ...
int aValue; // This is a int (primitive) variable
Integer someInteger = 12; // This is an Integer object
aValue = someInteger + 3; // aValue is still a `int` (primitive) variable
// ...
```

Some useful links:

- [The Set Interface (The Java Tutorials)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)
- [The `HashSet` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can do it as following:

```
int[] array = {0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();

for (int i : array) {
    set.add(i);
}

System.out.println("set = " + set);
```

And the result will be:

```
set = [-1, 0, 1, 3]
```